# how to detect tap anywhere on listview

Tags: android

I want an action to be performed every time I click on the screen . There is a list view inside Relative layout. When i set setOnCLickListener for relative layout alone when there is no listview inside it it is working but not with listview inside it. The items in the listview will be displayed only when I click on the screen each time . I tried setItemOnClickListener.Thats not working too.

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:clickable="true"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_msg"


        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_below="@+id/meLbl"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/black"
        android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
        android:divider="@null" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/meLbl"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:text="Amanda"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/friendLabel"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Janet"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20dp" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

The click is working only on the two text views not on the screen.
I want the click to work on the screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for find out clicked on screen :

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    Toast.makeText(SecondActivity.this, "click on screen ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

and for find out clicked on listView :

```
 listView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                Toast.makeText(SecondActivity.this, "Clicked On ListView", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return false;
            }
        });
```